# (how) can I use di< / di> to delete inner block of xml

Tags: cursor-motions

What would be the best way to delete / change the inner block of an xml element? I could use `df<` when my cursor is inside the block, i.e. when I have:

```
<elem>foo bar<\elem>
      ^
cursor location
```

`df<` from here should do it, but is there an inner block trick for this?

*noob here, so not sure what tags to use*

Comment: Isn't `cit` what you are looking for? `it` meaning `inner tag block`. `:help it`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the text-object `it` for in tag: `dit`, `cit`, &c. all do what you would expect.

There’s also `at` for a (whole) tag.

Comment: Thanks! what did you mean by *&c.*?

Comment: Just “et cetera”—if you know operators like delete, change, visually select, you can apply all of them to the text object. There are many operators, not including those from plugins like surround.vim or vim-commentary.